# Find letter in a String (charAt)

Tags: string, dart

I'm learning Dart now, and I was wondering how I can find  letters in a String. I've tried to use `charAt()`, but then the Dart Editor says:

> Class 'String' has no instance method 'charAt'.

So my question is: How can I find letters in a String in Dart?

For example, I want to find the `"i"` in the word `"fire"`. How does this work without `charAt()`?

```dart
var items = "fire";

for (int i = 0; items.length; i++) {
  if (items.indexOf(items(charAt(i)) != -1) {
    //..
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't post my answer as answer so I try as comment: I think

<!-- language: lang-dart -->

    items.indexOf('i');

    print(items.indexOf('i')); // prints: 1 because 'i' is found on the 2nd position

is what you are looking for, but you already use it in your question.

Comment: Your code makes no sense, if you just want to find out whether there is an `i` in a JS string value, then using `.indexOf("i")` is enough already, without any loops.

Comment: I also can't post an answer. charAt was implemented as the [] operator.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As said in comments, you don't have to create your own function since [indexOf / allMatches / contains](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_indexOf) are quiet enough for most of case.

And there is no charAt() equivalent since String act as a list of characters. You can use the [[] operator](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_%5B%5D) to get a letter at a specific index:

```dart
'Hello World'[6] //return 'W'
```

Comment: This is correct except that "String act as a list of characters" is not true. To actually get a list of characters use the split method, ex: `List<String> ListOfChar = myString.split('');`

Answer (score 9):

I think

```dart
items.indexOf('i');

print(items.indexOf('i')); // prints: 1 because 'i' is found on the 2nd position
```

is what you are looking for, but you already use it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the contains method!

Returns true if this string contains a match of [other]:

```
var string = 'Dart strings';
string.contains('D');                     // true
string.contains(new RegExp(r'[A-Z]'));    // true
```

If [startIndex] is provided, this method matches only at or after that
index:

```
string.contains('X', 1);                  // false
string.contains(new RegExp(r'[A-Z]'), 1); // false
```

[startIndex] must not be negative or greater than [length].

```
bool contains(Pattern other, [int startIndex = 0]);
```